# mysql query with subquery loop?

Tags: mysql, loops

I have a query

```
SELECT 
  count(product) as amount,
  product, 
  sum(price) AS price 
FROM `products` 
WHERE 
  brid = 'broker' 
AND 
  cancelled is null 
GROUP BY product 
WITH ROLLUP
```

Is it possible to query a table to get a brokers id and then for each broker run the query above written as 1 query?

Almost like:

```
SELECT brid FROM membership
THEN

SELECT 
  count(product) as amount,
  product, 
  sum(price) AS price 
FROM `products` 
WHERE 
  brid = membership.brid 
AND 
  cancelled is null 
GROUP BY product 
WITH ROLLUP

THEN
SELECT NEXT brid
```

Is this possible? i know how to do it in PHP but i would prefer 1 query that can create an array rather than tons of queries for each.

Thanks
Adam.

Answer (score 3):

Sure, you can GROUP BY both the 'brid' field and the 'product' field.  As noted below, `WITH ROLLUP` will cause it to sort by 'brid' and then by 'product':

```
SELECT
  brid, 
  count(product) as amount,
  product, 
  sum(price) AS price 
FROM `products` 
WHERE 
  brid IN (SELECT brid FROM membership)
AND 
  cancelled is null 
GROUP BY brid, product 
WITH ROLLUP
```

Comment: Tested in PhpMyAdmin and got --- #1221 - Incorrect usage of CUBE/ROLLUP and ORDER BY

Comment: You are correct, `WITH ROLLUP` precludes the use of `ORDER BY` and does the sorting for you already - so you can skip the ORDER BY clause.  Updated.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  count(product) as amount,
  product, 
  sum(price) AS price 
FROM `products` 
INNER JOIN membership on membership.brid = products.brid
WHERE 
  cancelled is null 
GROUP BY product 
WITH ROLLUP
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can understand from your example, all you need is `inner join between membership and products on brid`

Take the following example:

`products` table:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `price` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `product` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `brid` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cancelled` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL
)
```

`membership` table:

```
CREATE TABLE `membership` (
  `brid` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL
)
```

And following is my `query` as you required:

```
SELECT 
  t.brid, count(t.product) as amount,
  t.product, 
  sum(t.price) AS price 
FROM products t, membership m
WHERE 
  t.brid = m.`brid`
AND 
  cancelled is null 
GROUP BY product
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Would be better to express the join explicitly by moving the t.brid=m.brid into the from clause.